# Closing migrated questions as off-topic

Tags: discussion

I’m not sure I understand moving and closing questions stuff, but I’m wondering if it really makes sense to close questions [like this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59734/how-to-switch-from-mathjax-to-jqmath) as off-topic? I mean the user didn’t even ask the question on tex.stackechange and it isn’t his fault that someone else, inappropriately, moved the question here.

Comment: Whether a question is asked directly here or elsewhere does not affect whether it's on-topic for us. Other sites may see 'TeX' somewhere in a question and send it here without asking us first. What we can do in these cases is ask the original mods if we can send it back again.

Comment: Right, that what I meant IMO it should be sent back or migrated to a third place not be simply closed.

Comment: My understanding is that if we close it then the migration is "rejected" and it is sent back to the originating site.

Comment: actually, i was glad to have seen the mathjax question, since it is more than peripherally related to topics i'm vitally interested in, and i have no idea where else i might have looked.  (the majority of stackoverflow coverage isn't of enough relevance for me to follow the forum, so i wouldn't have seen this if it hadn't been migrated, however temporarily.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton StackOverflow has a mathjax tag, so it might be sufficient to follow that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Closing a migrated question as off-topic 'rejects' the migration, sending any answers back to the 'parent' site and leaving it unlocked there. That is how the system is set up, and allows us to keep our site on topic. The suggestion made in the mod chat was to delete  entirely from our site, but I am not sure that is useful.